# Bone broth question

Tags: food-safety, chicken, broth

Is it ok to partially cool chicken broth (prior to refrigerating ) with bones left in?  I left my chicken broth on a low simmer overnight, the next morning my husband turned the stock off to cool… He did not remove bones. Now I’m wondering if it is still safe to use (I removed bones and refrigerated stock within 2 hours)

Comment: Whether or not the bones are removed is irrelevant.  You might want to look at the related question on the right "I left stock out to cool overnight...", as it has information about cooling a stock.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact I would advise cooling the broth/stock a bit before putting it in the refrigerator. Adding hot foods to a refrigerator will drastically affect the foods inside. It takes too long to get from hot to cold and everything inside will be warmed up (to varying degrees) from the temperature fluctuation. Leaving the bones in, also not a problem. And it will make it easier to both skim the fat from the broth and remove the bones as the cooler temperatures will be easier to handle. Based on my experiences, everything sounds like you've handled it correctly.